# Shell script affects only on file instead of all of them

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am using a shell script to remove the XML tags of a set of files in a folder. This is how my file looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
find texts -type f -name '*.xml' -exec sh -c '
    mkdir -p modified
    file="$0"
    sed "s/<[^>]*>//g" "$file" > modified/modified_texts
' {} ';'
```

This is supposed to take all the files(using $file) in the "texts" folder, remove their XML tags and place the files without the XML tags into the file "modified".

The problem is that, instead of taking all the files, it is using just one, and filling the file "modified_texts" with the content of one of the files(without XML tags, that part works).

I don't really understand what I'm doing wrong, so I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Your multiline code formatting is wrong. Please fix it.

Comment: Use `>>` instead of `>`

Comment: As PhuNgo says -- your code runs over *every* file, but every file it processes, it deletes the current content of `modified_texts` and starts it over from the beginning; so only the last file's content is present in your result.

Comment: Better than switching from `>>` to `>`, though, is to keep `> modified/modified_texts` the same, but move it to be at the very end of your `find` command. That way instead of reopening the output file every time you run `sed`, you're opening the output file only once, before you start `find` at all, and keeping it open all the way through execution.

Comment: Thank You. That fixed it. I hadn't realised that

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing the output redirection (with truncation!) for every `sed` command, move it to the outer scope, so the output file is opened (and its prior contents are truncated) *only once*, before `find` is started at all.

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir -p modified  # this only needs to happen once, so move it outside
find texts -type f -name '*.xml' -exec sed 's/<[^>]*>//g' {} ';' > modified/modified_texts
```

Comment: This doesn't really seem to work for me. Using >> instead of > works, though. But thank you anyway

Comment: If you need to use `>>`, then you're opening the file more than once. You should fix whatever in your code is making it do that, instead of just doing a hacky workaround of making the opens nondestructive, while still re-opening the file over and over.

Comment: (to be clear, this answer, *exactly as given*, really does work; if you're trying to apply it and getting a failure, you'll need to show a reproducer for that failure before I can speak to it).

Comment: It depends on how the OP want to use the script. If they want to call it multiple times and each time append to the file, perhaps it would be better to merge the calls to open the file only once.